# Google Analytics heat maps

Tags: youtube, google-analytics

Is there any way to get the pages’ heat maps in Google Analytics?

If not, is there any way to count the watching of a YouTube video from a specific page?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics don't record the information to generate a page heatmaps. However you can add the Google Analytics' paid extension [SessionCam's Session Replay, Heatmaps and Web Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/apps/about?app_id=2256001) (free trial available), it will generate website heatmaps for mouse movement, mouse clicks, page scrolling and browser attention:

[image]

Comment: Thank! but is too match... and I need something in of gppgle... They are no way in youtube, to catch from where the video is opened?

Comment: I believe it used to be possible to see in a video statistics from which website the video has been watched but I don't know if this is still the case. Either way you should create another question for that as it has nothing to do with page heatmaps.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this tool could help you on your issue: http://miapex.com

I'm not affiliate with this tool. The tool allows me to compare 2 heatmaps on the same page with different filtering conditions and shows click/attention/scroll reach heatmaps for me website. It also supports heatmaps for PC and mobile webpages.